# Oracle+Web-приложение: Не удалось найти или загрузить зарегистрированного поставщика данных .Net Framework

Tags: веб-программирование, oracle

Осваиваю Web-программирование. Решаю для начала простейшую задачу - отобразить табличку из БД Oracle в окне браузера. Для этого создаю в VS Web-приложение, на форму перетаскиваю ASPxTreeList, затем справа наверху контрола кликаю треугольничек, выбираю "настроить источник данных", затем по шагам прохожу все шаги настройки. На форме отображается грид с моими столбцами. В конструкторе запросов VS тестирую запрос - он выполняется без проблем, данные отображаются. Пока всё так же, как в родном windows-приложении. Далее по [инструкции](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/19.3/odpnt/InstallConfig.html#GUID-1F689B90-2CC4-4907-B8FE-A5F4EE36F673) вставляю в machine.config строки:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
      <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.19.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
...
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.19.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

,исправляя версию на свою Version=4.122.19.3. PublicKeyToken не исправляю, поскольку взять его неоткуда, да и в инструкции не пишут его менять. name=ODP.NET, Managed Driver соответствует выбранному мной при настройке источника данных.

**Проблема**: после запуска из VS приложения оно пишет мне:

```
Ошибка сервера в приложении '/'.
Не удалось найти или загрузить зарегистрированного поставщика данных .Net Framework.
Описание: Необработанное исключение при выполнении текущего веб-запроса. Изучите трассировку стека для получения дополнительных сведений о данной ошибке и о вызвавшем ее фрагменте кода.
Сведения об исключении: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Не удалось найти или загрузить зарегистрированного поставщика данных .Net Framework.
Ошибка источника:
[Отсутствуют соответствующие исходные строки]
Исходный файл: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\97e9fc7a\62004861\App_Web_sidizfx5.0.cs    Строка: 0
Трассировка стека:
[ConfigurationErrorsException: Не удалось найти или загрузить зарегистрированного поставщика данных .Net Framework.]
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DataRow providerRow) +1044777
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName) +88
```

Пробовал идти другим путём: брал шаблон приложения DevExpress Template Galery, заменял источник данных в таблице шаблона так же, как описал в начале, шаблон переставал работать с той же ошибкой.

**Вопрос**: что я делаю не так? Почему в среде разработки "поставщик данных" имеется, а в runtime "исчезает"?
Буду признателен за совет, куда копать.

Comment: Маленькое уточнение: в machine.config во всех строках нужно писать имя провайдера С БОЛЬШИМИ БУКВАМИ: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client, иначе начинает виснуть построитель запросов VS.

Comment: Установил Devart dotConnect и - о чудо -  после перехода на этого провайдера данные в runtime появились. Проблему я таким образом для себя решил, но почему не заработал Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client - осталось загадкой. Видимо, проблема в какой-то неверной строчке в machine.config, которую сам ODT не прописывает при установке, а мне не допендрить...